# Blazor WebAssembly;.net core SignalR Client;Throw InvalidOperationException When Invoke HubConnectionBuilder.Builder()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor-client-side

[Copy code from this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

The blazor project(.net standard 2.1)

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly 3.2.1
2. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build 3.2.1
3. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer 3.2.1
4. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client 3.1.6
5. Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 3.1.6
6. Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson 3.1.6
7. System.Net.Http.Json 3.2.1

```
@code{
  private HubConnection HC;
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
    HC = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:4000/class").Build();
    HC.On<string>("TextMessage", Message => Console.WriteLine(Message));
    await HC.StartAsync();
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
  }
}
```

Log in chrome console:

[image]

asp.net core Server:(.net core 3.1)

```
 public class Startup {
     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
          Configuration = configuration;
     }

     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
         services.AddSingleton<ClassHub>();
         services.AddSignalR(o => {
             o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = null;
             o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
         });
     }
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env){
         app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
             endpoints.MapHub<ClassHub>("/class", options => {
                 options.TransportMaxBufferSize = 256000;
                 options.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = 256000;
             });
         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: top part in log:
System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

Comment: I fixed this problem without modify any code,
first remove all references and razor files exclude web assembly,http.json ,main layout and index page;
then add them back exclude Microssoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client because i don't need class HttpConnectionFactory;
problem fixed,but don't know why.

Comment: I have the same problem. It occured one time but after a page reload it worked so I thought it was just some random error but then, after a second publish the problem came again but didn't go away... no good solution so far.

Comment: @ZoyuJ - How do you add SignalR without the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client package? Its a dependency of SignalR

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. I was using Blazor WebAssembly and an ASP Api Rest for the chat hub. When I runned Blazor app this crashed. I struggled alote and was googling.

However I fixed it just installing a Nuget. Make sure `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client` Nuget is installed. Just Installed as a Nuget and that's it.

[image: See nuggets I installed, here]